# Segmentation Fault, c program

Tags: c

Why does these code returning a segmentation fault? I searched online but can't find the problem. Could you please help?
Is it because of pointer malloc fault?

```
void multiply(int **a, int n, int m, int **b, int m2, int p, int **c)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < p; j++){
            for (k = 0; k < m; k++){
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            printf("%d", c);}}
}
main()
{
    int **a, **b, **c;
    int n, m, p;
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d", &n); scanf("%d", &m); scanf("%d", &p);
    a = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));}
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);}
    }
    b = (int **)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        b[i] = (int *)malloc(p*sizeof(int));}
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < p; j++){
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);}
    }
    c = (int **)malloc(n, sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        c[i] = (int *)malloc(p, sizeof(int));
    multiply(a, n, m, b, m, p, c);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
}
```

Thanks^^

I edit some code and it is now correct. Thank you guys so much.
Cheers!

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just debug this in the usual way, e.g. step through the code in your debugger and see what's going on ?

Comment: `c = calloc(n, sizeof(int *));`

Comment: multiply(**a, n, m, **b, m, p, **c); -> multiply(a, n, m, b, m, p, c); i can't imagine a compiler not warning about that.

Comment: Enable you're compiler warnings to pedantic levels. There are multiple issues in your code they will identify, and *all* of them need to be fixed.

Comment: free(a), free(b), free(c); you called malloc and friends more than 3 times..

Comment: multiply(**a, n, m, **b, m, p, **c);->I'm sorry that it's a fault of copying...

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an LP64 architecture (int is 32 bits and int* is 64 bits), c is too small, you should use

```
c = (int **)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

```
        for (k = 0; k < m; j++){
                           ^
```

This should be:

```
        for (k = 0; k < m; k++){
                           ^
```

Also:

```
multiply(**a, n, m, **b, m, p, **c);
```

should be:

```
multiply(a, n, m, b, m, p, c);
```

***Note that if you had turned on compiler warnings then the compiler would have helpfully pointed out this mistake to you.***

Note also that [you should not cast the result of malloc in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Look at the function call ..multiply() that is the issue and hence segmentation fault

Comment: I think there is more than one issue, but this one certainly needs to be fixed.